# AWS IoT SDK: use MQTT over TCP Port 443

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, aws-iot

According to [this document](https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/iot/mqtt-with-tls-client-authentication-on-port-443-why-it-is-useful-and-how-it-works/), using MQTT on port 443 in AWS IoT requires configuring the ALPN extension with the `x-amzn-mqtt-ca` protocol.

I use the AWS IoT C++ SDK with OpenSSL. When creating the `network::OpenSSLConnection` object, I configured the `endpoint_port` parameter to 443 and `enable_alpn` to true. Where can I set the protocol to `x-amzn-mqtt-ca`? The connection seems to work that way, and TCPView shows that it actually uses the HTTPS port.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try setting the following two protected variables too during *network::OpenSSLConnection(..)*?

```
SSL_CTX *p_ssl_context_;  ///< SSL Context instance
SSL     *p_ssl_handle_;   ///< SSL Handle
```

More info on how to set specific ALPN protocols is on OpenSSL docs @ [here](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/man3/SSL_set_alpn_protos.html).

Hope that helps!